# onchange event on checkbox always shows this.value = on

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

An input of type checkbox when fires its `onchange` event the `this.value` is always set to `on` even when the checkbox is ticked off in which case I'd expect it to be `off`

Is this the intended behavior?

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="alert(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

short answer: do not use `value` to check checked status on checkboxes, use `checked` instead

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="alert(this.checked)">
```

and in case that you wonder why is this always-"on" value, there's a specification for that in HTML5 specification:

> **default/on**
>
> On getting, if the element has a value attribute, it must return that
>   attribute's value; otherwise, **it must return the**
>   **string "on"**. On setting, it must set the element's value attribute to
>   the new value.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value-default-on